# Node.js & Redis & For Loop with bluebird Promises?

Tags: node.js, for-loop, redis, promise, bluebird

i want a function that makes a new JSON Object that looks so :

```
{ T-ID_12 : [{ text: "aaaaa", kat:"a" }], T-ID_15 : [{ text: "b", kat:"ab" }],  T-ID_16 : [{ text: "b", kat:"ab" }] }
```

This `{ text: "aaaaa", kat:"a" }` in thesenjsondata and this `T-ID_12` is an entry of the array Thesen_IDS. And my solution so far is :

```
function makeThesenJSON(number_these, Thesen_IDS){
var thesenjsondata;
var thesenids_with_jsondata = "";

for (i = 0; i < number_these; i++ ){

    db.getAsync(Thesen_IDS[i]).then(function(res) {
        if(res){
            thesenjsondata = JSON.parse(res);
            thesenids_with_jsondata += (Thesen_IDS[i] + ' : [ ' + thesenjsondata + " ], ");

        }

    });

}

var Response = "{ " + thesenids_with_jsondata + " }" ;
return Response;
}
```

I know, that the for-loop is faster then the db.getAsync(). How can i use the bluebird promises with redis right, so that the return value has all data that i want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just create an array of promises out of Redis calls, then use Bluebird's `Promise.all` to wait for all to come back as an array.

```
function makeThesenJSON(number_these, Thesen_IDS) {

  return Promise.all(number_these.map(function (n) {
      return db.GetAsync(Thesen_IDS[n]);
     }))
    .then(function(arrayOfResults) {
      var thesenids_with_jsondata = "";
      for (i = 0; i < arrayOfResults.length; i++) {
        var res = arrayOfResults[i];
        var thesenjsondata = JSON.parse(res);
        thesenids_with_jsondata += (Thesen_IDS[i] + ' : [ ' + thesenjsondata + " ], ");
      }
      return "{ " + thesenids_with_jsondata + " }";
    })
}
```

Note how this function is Async because it returns a Promise that will eventually resolve to a string. So you call it like this:

```
makeThesenJSON.then(function (json) {
  //do something with json
})
```

Comment: the return of the function is now {
"isFulfilled": false
"isRejected": false
}

Comment: thx, it's working, but i had to "var thesenjsondata = JSON.parse(res);" change to "var thesenjsondata = res;"

Comment: Glad I could help!